# Problem with compiling BibTex: "no \citation commands" error

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I'm really new to BibTex, I just wonder what is going wrong when I have this kind of error when I try to compile my bibliography file.

`I found no \citation commands---while reading file masterthesis.aux`

I have put this `\bibliographystyle{plain}` and `bibliography{masterthesis}` somewhere in my document, but I don't know what to do here...

Comment: It can't find any `\cite` commands in your document.

Comment: put `\nocite{*}` before the bibliography command

Comment: You have not cited any of your bibliography entries. By default bibtex insert in the bibliography only the cited entries, so if you want to include all of your records in the bibliographi use the `\nocite{*}` command before `\printbibliography`

Comment: @zfm "problem with compiling bibtex" is not a particularly descriptive title...

Comment: I know this is old, but I got this error even though I DID have citations in the text.  I had to change my bibdata reference from Filename.bib to Filename.bib.bib, and that worked.

Comment: @JKelly are you sure that the file is not actually named "Filename.bib.bib"? That happens very often, if your OS hides the file extension :-D

Comment: I've tried the solutions here but they were of no help. This [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/369691/145331) worked for me: ensure you use `\renewcommand*` and not `RenewDocumentCommand` from `xparse`! I'm commenting here since I do not have enough reputation, hoping that this solution might help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

As explained on the second page of the BIBTeX manual the new command `\nocite{*}` allows, since version 0.99b, to

> include in the reference list every entry in the database files, without having to explicitly \cite or \nocite each entry. Giving this command, in essence, \nocites all the enties in the database, in database order, at the very spot in your document where you give the command.

This is useful since BIBTeX, by default, do not consider uncited entries of the database. This behaviour can look strange but is the right way to proceed: if you don't cite anything, it means that you haven't used any information from the entries in the database in your document! So the best way to proceed is to find a place to cite every entry.

Answer (score 103):

I noticed this problem when I used `biblatex` without having specified the `backend=bibtex` package option. Adding the option fixed it.

Comment: The most recent version of `biblatex` assumes the usage of Biber rather than BibTeX for processing the bibliography. Thus `biber filename` rather than `bibtex filename` is required, unless you specify `backend=bibtex` that, on the other hand, will put `biblatex` in a sort of "compatibility mode" and make it impossible to benefit from the new features of version 2.

Comment: for me I use `backend=biber` but I forgot to install biber on the new machine

Comment: This answer solves so many other posts...

Comment: Let me just reiterate egreg's point: For most users the better solution (even if it appears to be harder at first) is **not** to go for `backend=bibtex,`. Users should go for `backend=biber,` and change their workflow/configure their editor to run Biber instead of BibTeX. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864. BibTeX is only supported as a legacy backend in `biblatex`. The full feature set can only be used with Biber.

Answer (score 79):

I'm a `TeXstudio` user and whenever *I* receive this error message, it's because I've changed the default bibliography tool from `biber` to `bibtex`.

To change it back, I have to do `Options > Configure TeXstudio > Build > Default Bibliography Tool` and the process works again.

Even if this answer never helps anyone else ever, it'll at least be good for me to have this here as a *aide memoire* next times this happens!

Comment: Same with TexShop: `Preferences > Engine` and change the default BibTeX Engine to `biber`.

Comment: Really from `biber` to `biblatex`? Or from `bibtex` to `biber`?

Comment: If you add `% !BIB TS-program = biber` at the beginning of your document you don't need to change the default bibliography tool anymore

Comment: Changing this from `bibtex` to `biber` has made it work for me.

Comment: Changing to biber worked, but it caused TeXstudio to crash on the first iteration. After running it a second time, it worked. I also used @Taekwondavide 's comment so that this doesn't become a problem again, and it's works great.

Comment: In TeXMaker, it is- **configure texmaker** > **commands** > **bib(la)tex** to **biber %**.

Comment: This saved me, thanks haha

Comment: If you have configured your .tex to use biber, but you compile the file with biblatex, then this error occurs. So, your citation backend needs to be biber (\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex} in preable, or similar) in order for this answer to work.

Comment: Helpe me, thanks!

Comment: In my case it was basically the other way around. Backend was biber but TeXstudio used Bibtex. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 19):

I know this is kind of an old thread but I had exactly the same problem and this solution was not helpful.

Make sure that your LaTeX document is structured correctly. I spent the last 30 minutes trying to figure out why BibTeX couldn't find any `\citation` commands when the problem was actually that I hadn't closed a `\section{}` properly. I guess as you become used to error messages regarding references on the first LaTeX run you can miss the details.

Comment: Thank you so very much! None of the answers worked for me except this one.

Comment: It's really useful. How does this work?

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar issue before. I searched online for hours to find the solution and finally figured out.

You will get the error `no \citation commands---while reading file` when you don't cite the references that you mention in bib file!

What does citation mean?
Before discussing what citation means, let's talk about the purpose of the bibliography. Bibliography is the section where you mention the list of references you went through (papers s or books you read). This helps the people to read those references when they don't find enough info in your paper. So, whenever you mention a particular term or sentence (referring to some paper in your bibliography section), you will be citing that term to that paper.

eg:

```
The issue_x is because of term_y \cite{cite_key}
```

In the bib file

```
@author{cite_key,
 author = {xxxxx},
 title = {yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy},
 year = {zzzzzz},
 publisher = {ppppppp.},
 address = {wwwwwwwwww},
}
```

So, In order to display the bibliography information, you have to cite the reference in you tex file as shown in the example.

Is there way you could mention the bibliography without citings?

Yes, as suggested by spike, you can use 
`\nocite{*}` (if you are not referring to any reference mentioned in bib)
`\nocite{cite_key}` (reference with specific key)

Hope this helps someone! Sorry if I am wrong in my explanation but this is how I solved my issue.

Comment: It might be helpful if you turned your example of a "`.tex`" file with citation into a full and complete [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that); see also [MWEB](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography).