# printbibliography is printing nothing

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I'm using biblatex to print my bibliography at the end of my thesis but unfortunately nothing is printed at the end (not even a blank page).

Here's an example of what I'm using:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper, width=150mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm, bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}
I'm goint to cite the first reference with \cite{einstein}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Here's what my .bib file looks like:

```
@article{einstein,
    author =       "Albert Einstein",
    title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
    [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
    journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
    volume =       "322",
    number =       "10",
    pages =        "891--921",
    year =         "1905",
    DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004",
    keywords =     "physics"
}

@book{dirac,
    title={The Principles of Quantum Mechanics},
    author={Paul Adrien Maurice Dirac},
    isbn={9780198520115},
    series={International series of monographs on physics},
    year={1981},
    publisher={Clarendon Press},
    keywords = {physics}
}
```

**EDIT:**
[image]

What might be the problem?

Comment: What is the relative location of the file references.bib to the main .tex file? do you compile using `bibtex` command ?

Comment: Did you call biber? What does the .blg-file say?

Comment: Did you run the usual cycle: `pdflatex -> biber -> pdflatex (twice)`?

Comment: Works well in Overleaf so I guess you have a filename/path error. Or the building cycle is missing some steps.

Comment: I'm using Texmaker. How do I run biber, please?

Comment: Please have a look at [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864) for help on how to set up Biber in your favourite editor. You might also want to have a look at [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864) for a bit of background.

Comment: So I ran biber several times and all but it still gives nothing. It says "Empty bibliography" in a warning message. @UlrikeFischer

Comment: Could you also answer my second question?

Comment: I have added an image in my post. @UlrikeFischer

Comment: If your editor is set up to run Biber correctly, you should be able to find a `.blg` file (the log file Biber writes). Just paste its contents to your question.

Comment: No, you are showing only the output of your editor regarding the log-file. I asked about the `.blb` file.

Comment: Oh right, sorry. In a minute...

Comment: This is BibTeX, Version 0.99dThe top-level auxiliary file: final.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file final.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file final.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file final.aux
(There were 3 error messages)
@UlrikeFischer

Comment: That definitely shows that you run BibTeX and not Biber. Please check out the two links I posted above for help on how to run Biber.

Comment: [0] Config.pm:324> INFO - This is Biber 2.1
[1] Config.pm:327> INFO - Logfile is 'final.blg'
[148] biber-MSWIN:273> INFO - === %a %b %e, %Y, %H:%M:%S
[149] Biber.pm:333> INFO - Reading 'final.bcf'
[876] Utils.pm:146> WARN - Warning: Found biblatex control file version 3.1, expected version 2.7
[878] Biber.pm:645> INFO - Found 0 citekeys in bib section 0
[879] Utils.pm:146> WARN - The file 'final.bcf' does not contain any citations!
[945] bbl.pm:505> INFO - Writing 'final.bbl' with encoding 'UTF-8'
[951] bbl.pm:596> INFO - Output to final.bbl
[952] Biber.pm:106> INFO - WARNINGS: 2

Comment: Here above is what I get. @moewe

Comment: Well, now that shows that your versions of `biblatex` and Biber are out of sync. You need to do an update. Since you are running MikTeX you will have to run the Updater in Admin and in User mode (you may have to run both of the updaters twice). See also [How should one maintain and update a MiKTeX installation?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108447/35864)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved by an updating and running Biber. (The OP's self answer seems to address an unrelated issue...)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! All I had to do was cite each reference at least once and they appear in the bibliography section. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Mhh, would you say that is the solution offered in [Problem with compiling BibTex: “no \citation commands” error](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18045/35864)? Interestingly, I would say that is not the problem that your MWE above suffers from.

Comment: @meowe I can't say if it is or not the problem but my bibliography is created and printed.