# renewcommand cite

Tags: citing

if I write the `\cite{Key}` command in the continuous text my citation is not superscript.
If I write `\textsuperscript{\cite{Key}}` it does exactly look what I prefer.

My question is if there's a possible to renwecommand the `\cite` command, because I don't want to change it everywhere in my document by hand.
My concept was something like that:

```
\renwecommand{\cite}{\textsuperscript{\cite{#}}}
```

But it doesn't work, probably because I don't know how to use renwecommand.
I'm using scrreprt.

I hope anyone can help me.
Michael

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Should all, or just some, citation call-outs be placed in superscript positions? Do you use a citation management package such as `cite` or `natbib`? Please advise.

Comment: And if hours use bibtex and the natbib package this is even an option to natbib  so you do not have to do anything. I think it's called super

Answer (score 10):

Your attempt has a couple of problems:

- It should be `\renewcommand` or `\renewcommand*` instead of `\renwecommand`.
- You need to specify the number of arguments with `[1]` if you have a single argument. Then you can refer to the argument with a number, *i.e.* `#1` instead of `#`.
- Since you overwrite `\cite`, you need to let LaTeX know that you want to refer to `\cite` as it was *before* your redefinition. You can do this by defining a new command `\oldcite` that stores the original definition of `\cite`.

The following code should work:

```
\let\oldcite\cite
\renewcommand*\cite[1]{\textsuperscript{\oldcite{#1}}}
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider using natbib package with "super" option, e.g.,

```
 \usepackage[super,comma,sort&compress]{natbib}
```

The natbib package will take you a couple of minutes to learn, but will give a lot of flexibility in defining your citation styles.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[square,comma,sort&compress,numbers]{natbib}% style [1,4-6]
\usepackage[super,comma,sort&compress,numbers]{natbib}  % style  ^{1,4-6}

\begin{document}

Citation \cite{<cite1>,..,<citeN>}.

Citation with citep \citep{<cite1>}.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{<your bibliography bib file>}

\end{document}
```

Note (optional): If you prefer to be explicit on using "numbers" and "not names" in your citation, use \citep{} instead of \cite{}.

Comment: You might want to add on some note about *not* using `\cite` with `natbib` package and what the alternatives provided by `natbib` are, for a more complete answer (considering OP's question is about using `\cite`.

Comment: For a short and useful description of the natbib options see https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Bibliography_management_with_natbib