# Redefine \citealt to avoid creating hyperlink

Tags: hyperref, citing, natbib

My document has lots of natbib citations of the general form

```
 \citealt[462]{Andrews1982b}
```

— which I would like to not create hyperlinks, while using the HyperRef package to produce other hyperlinks.  I believe a way do do this is with \renewcommand.  Adapting a suggestion from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/369689/renewcommand-cite), I've tried:

```
\let\oldcitealt\citealt
\renewcommand*\citealt[2]{\begin{NoHyper}\oldcitealt[#1]{#2}\end{NoHyper}}
```

which appears to just disable the whole thing.  How can I do this?

EDIT: MWEB (as requested by @samcarter)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{Andrews1982b,
    Address = {Cambridge, Mass.},
    Author = {Andrews, Avery},
    Booktitle = {The Mental Representation of Grammatical Relations},
    Date-Modified = {2018-01-18 20:29:31 +0000},
    Editor = {Bresnan, Joan},
    Keywords = {Icelandic; quirky case; grammatical relation; agreement; subcategorisation},
    Pages = {426-503},
    Publisher = {MIT Press},
    Title = {The representation of case in Modern {Icelandic}},
    Year = {1982}}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% what makes it not work
\let\oldcitealt\citealt 
\renewcommand*\citealt[2]{\begin{NoHyper}\oldcitealt[#1]{#2}\end{NoHyper}}
%

\begin{document}
Things are true (\citealt{Andrews1982b}).

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please make a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407)?

Comment: @samcarter done!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you forgot to specify the optional argument in your `\renewcommand`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{Andrews1982b,
    Address = {Cambridge, Mass.},
    Author = {Andrews, Avery},
    Booktitle = {The Mental Representation of Grammatical Relations},
    Date-Modified = {2018-01-18 20:29:31 +0000},
    Editor = {Bresnan, Joan},
    Keywords = {Icelandic; quirky case; grammatical relation; agreement; subcategorisation},
    Pages = {426-503},
    Publisher = {MIT Press},
    Title = {The representation of case in Modern {Icelandic}},
    Year = {1982}}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% with the optional argument, it works
\let\oldcitealt\citealt
\renewcommand*\citealt[2][]{\begin{NoHyper}\oldcitealt[#1]{#2}\end{NoHyper}}

\begin{document}
Things are true (\citealt{Andrews1982b}).

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image]