# Biblatex bibliography in beamer does not work (name of the articles in bold)

Tags: beamer, biblatex, bibliographies

Using biblatex I don't obtain the name of the reference but the name of the article - in the .bib - file in bold.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\insertbiblabel}

\mode<presentation> {\usetheme{Madrid}  
    }

\usepackage{graphicx} % Allows including images
\usepackage{booktabs} % Allows the use of \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule in tables

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{presentation.bib}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\title[Short title]{Proyecto de Tesis: Holografía y sistemas integrables} % The short title appears at the bottom of every slide, the full title is only on the title page

\author{John Smith} % Your name
\institute[UCLA] % Your institution as it will appear on the bottom of every slide, may be shorthand to save space
{
University of California \\ % Your institution for the title page
\medskip
\textit{john.smith@example.com} % Your email address
}
\date{\today} % Date, can be changed to a custom date

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage % Print the title page as the first slide
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline} % Table of contents slide, comment this block out to remove it
\tableofcontents % Throughout your presentation, if you choose to use \section{} and \subsection{} commands, these will automatically be printed on this slide as an overview of your presentation
\end{frame}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PRESENTATION SLIDES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%------------------------------------------------

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{Resumen}

Las p-formas autoduales se definen en dimensión $d=2(p+1)$, donde $p$ es par . Su caso más sencillo, con $p=0$, corresponde al bosón quiral . Esta ecuación aparece como un caso particular de la denominada ``jerarquía de KdV''. Dicha jerarquía se puede formular como una acción de Chern-Simons en una dimensión extra, escogiendo condiciones de borde adecuadas para la conexión. El objetivo de esta tesis es generalizar esta construcción con el fin de generar sistemas integrables para p-formas en dimensiones superiores, con aplicaciones a supergravedad en seis dimensiones \cite{Marcus:1982yu}.

\end{frame}

%------------------------------------------------

%------------------------------------------------


\begin{frame}
\Huge{\centerline{Muchas gracias.}}
\end{frame}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

My purpose is being able to use the `\footfullcite` command. I've read [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135484/still-biblatex-will-not-print-bibliography) and [this articles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18045/problem-with-compiling-bibtex-no-citation-commands-error) but I don't know the problem.

Comment: You must run the example with Biber instead of BibTeX, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864.

Comment: Please add code and log messages as text and not as an image. Images make stuff hard to copy and search, images are not indexed by search engines and can be an accessibility issues for people with screen readers. For future questions you may want to try and minimise the code examples in the sense of https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864 and https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864. Much of the code shown in the example document is not related to citations and the bibliography at all and could be left out with the same basic results.

Comment: For the first comment: Did what the page says, but nothing happened; the problem remains.

For the second comment: My mistake. Will edit my question. Thanks.

Comment: The screenshot shown in the question clearly shows that you run BibTeX (`This is BibTeX`). But your document setup requires you to run Biber instead. Follow the link to find out how to let your editor run Biber instead of BibTeX. Then delete the temporary files (`.aux`, `.bbl`, `.bcf`, ...) and run LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX (where 'LaTeX' is your favourite LaTeX flavour, for example pdfLaTeX or LuaLaTeX). Then check the `.blg` file for info.

Comment: Ok, I did the instructions, but appear this message: "could not start Build & View: PdfLaTeX: pdflatex.exe - synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "references".tex"

Comment: Mhhh that is odd. You didn't change any of the `pdflatex` settings, did you? Only Biber is relevant and the rest shouldn't have changed, so there is no reason that the editor should start to complain about pdfLaTeX all of a sudden.

Comment: Any news here? As the *question* stands now the best answer is 'use Biber instead of BibTeX' and therefore the question is a duplicate of the one I linked in my first comment. But apparently there were other issues as well. Were you able to resolve those?

Comment: I'll vote to close your question as a duplicate of the 'use Biber in your editor' question. If you are still having (different) trouble with your installation, I suggest you ask a new question about that.